# Update Nested fields using Golang struct

Tags: go

I am facing a issue with update struct fields using golang

As the var name suggest some current config fields should be updated with the requested config

```
     currentConfig:=`
     {
         "field_one": "value",
         "data": {
             "field_two": [
                 "data1",
                 "data2"
             ],
             "field_three": "check",
             "field_four": 12
         },
        "field_five": [
                 "data1",
                 "data2"
             ],
        "data2": {
            "field_six":{
                "field_seven": 100
            }
        }
     }`
    
     
     updateRequest:=`
     {
         "data": {
             "field_three": "updated check" //ignore if same value exist (field_three exists in current config)
         },
        "field_five": ["data3"],    // append to current config
        "data2": {
            "field_six":{
                "field_eight": 300  // add value if doesnt exist to current
            }
        }
     }`
```

```
func main() {
    config := make(map[string]interface{})
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(currentConfig), &config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    updateFields := make(map[string]interface{})
    err1 := json.Unmarshal([]byte(updateRequest), &updateFields)
    if err1 != nil {
        panic(err1)
    } 

    fmt.Println(config)
    updateFields = ParseJsonMap(updateFields, config)
    fmt.Println(updateFields)
}


func ParseJsonMap(aMap map[string]interface{}, finalMap map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    parseMap("", aMap, &finalMap)
    return finalMap
}
```

Traverses the struct and updates the fields

```
func parseMap(k string, aMap map[string]interface{}, finalMap *map[string]interface{}) {
    if len(aMap) == 0 {
        (*finalMap)[k] = nil
        return
    }

    for key, val := range aMap {
        if val != nil {
            switch concreteVal := val.(type) {
            case map[string]interface{}:
                if _, ok := (*finalMap)[getKey(k, key)]; ok {
                    parseMap(getKey(k, key), val.(map[string]interface{}), finalMap)
                } else {
                    (*finalMap)[getKey(k, key)] = val
                }
            case []interface{}:
                res := val.([]interface{})
                if arr, ok := (*finalMap)[getKey(k, key)]; ok {
                    for _, valueIn := range res {
                        arr = append(arr.([]interface{}), valueIn)
                    }
                    (*finalMap)[getKey(k, key)] = arr
                } else {
                    (*finalMap)[getKey(k, key)] = res
                }
                
            default:
                concreteValType := reflect.TypeOf(concreteVal)
                if concreteValType.Kind() == reflect.Map {
                    parseMap(getKey(k, key), concreteVal.(map[string]interface{}), finalMap)
                } else {
                    if _, ok := (*finalMap)[getKey(k, key)]; !ok {
                        (*finalMap)[getKey(k, key)] = concreteVal
                    }

                }
            }
        } else {
            (*finalMap)[getKey(k, key)] = nil
        }
    }
}

func getKey(k string, key string) string {
    if k == "" {
        return key
    }

    return k + "." + key
}
```

Expected Result

```
map[data:map[field_four:12 field_three:check field_two:[data1 data2]] data2:map[field_six:map[field_eight:300 field_seven:100]] field_five:[data1 data2 data3] field_one:value]
```

```
{
         "field_one": "value",
         "data": {
             "field_two": [
                 "data1",
                 "data2"
             ],
             "field_three": "check",  //since key exist with data not updated
             "field_four": 12
         },
        "field_five": [
                 "data1",
                 "data2",
                 "data3"   //data 3 appended
             ],
        "data2": {
            "field_six":{
                "field_seven": 100,
                "field_eight": 300 //field is added
            }
        }
     }
```

Result got - created key at top level

```
map[data:map[field_four:12 field_three:check field_two:[data1 data2]] data.field_three:check changed data2:map[field_six:map[field_seven:100]] data2.field_six:map[field_eight:300] field_five:[data1 data2 data3] field_one:value]
```

Just want to know if this is supported, if yes can you help me with it and if any better approaches exist

Comment: You seem to be attaching some significance to the `.` used in `getKeys` but json spec does not.   If you want to change `field_three` under `data` or whatever,  you need to do it within that map,  not within the parent map with a dot in the key.   That's JSON's rule.

Comment: Correct. I was looking into implementing that have no idea as to how to achieve that. Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Note that Go does have actual struct types but in your code there is not a single struct there. You might want to be more precise when describing the problem for which you would like a solution.

Comment: Okay. ill define the struct

Comment: Generally I'm a big fan of modeling data in `struct`s, but in this case `struct`s don't help much, since the keys are not known.  Using `interface{}`, `[]interface{}`, and `map[string]interface{}` with type checks makes sense to me

Comment: Correct. initially i did start defining the struct ended up with this more generic approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you're trying to overlay one map onto another map. This gets complicated if you don't want to apply this kind of update without altering an existing map. So it may be easier to separate the two steps:

- Copy a `map[string]interface{}`
- overlay one `map[string]interface{}` on top of another

---

```
func CopyMap(m map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    cp := make(map[string]interface{})
    for k, v := range m {
        vm, ok := v.(map[string]interface{})
        if ok {
            cp[k] = CopyMap(vm)
        } else {
            cp[k] = v
        }
    }
    return cp
}
```

---

```
func overlay(dst, src map[string]interface{}) error {
    for k, v := range src {

        if _, ok := dst[k]; !ok {
            dst[k] = v // easy case - dst key does not exist
            continue
        }

        d, ok1 := dst[k].(map[string]interface{})
        s, ok2 := src[k].(map[string]interface{})

        if ok1 && ok2 {
            overlay(d, s) // merge case
        } else if !ok1 && !ok2 {
            dst[k] = v // non-map - so simple assignment/reassignment
        } else {
            return fmt.Errorf("incompatible update types") // map to non-map or vice-versa
        }

    }
    return nil
}
```

to use:

```
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(currentConfig), &config) // check err
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(updateRequest), &updateFields) // check err
newconfig = CopyMap(config)
err = overlay(newconfig, updateFields) // check err
```

https://play.golang.org/p/RZPbkv19ChL

Output:

```
    config : map[data:map[field_four:12 field_three:check field_two:[data1 data2]] data2:map[field_six:map[field_eight:200 field_seven:100]] field_five:[data1 data2] field_one:value]
    update : map[data:map[field_three:check changed] data2:map[field_six:map[field_eight:300]] field_five:[data1]]
 newconfig : map[data:map[field_four:12 field_three:check changed field_two:[data1 data2]] data2:map[field_six:map[field_eight:300 field_seven:100]] field_five:[data1] field_one:value]
```

---

UPDATE: to handle appends rather than replacements for JSON arrays:

```
func overlay2(dst, src map[string]interface{}) error {
    for k, v := range src {

        if _, ok := dst[k]; !ok {
            dst[k] = v // easy case - dst key does not exist
            continue
        }

        dm, ok1 := dst[k].(map[string]interface{})
        sm, ok2 := src[k].(map[string]interface{})

        if ok1 && ok2 {
            overlay2(dm, sm) // merge case
            continue
        }

        ds, ok1 := dst[k].([]interface{})
        ss, ok2 := src[k].([]interface{})

        if ok1 && ok2 {
            dst[k] = append(ds, ss...) // JSON array case
            continue
        }

        return fmt.Errorf("unhandled type/update")

    }
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/i-0yXMcqU7Z

Comment: thank you @colm.anseo for your effort.  i forgot to add that the config should be updated based on certain conditions. have updated the question with comments in config.

Comment: this is close, except it doesn't quite handle `"field_five":["data3"]`.  According to desired results it should *append* to existing `field_five`, not replace entire array.

Comment: @DanielFarrell that requirement wasn't in the original question. Updating by append seems like a bad approach. How would one make an update to delete elements from the array? It would not be possible with this approach.

Comment: @user17090811 you may need to rethink your update strategy. Appending to an array list is fine, but how would you delete from an array list? I think replacement is the best strategy to cover both new assignment, addition & deletion of elements.

Comment: @colm.anseo deleting usecase wont come, append to array if key exist else create that and for struct if same key exist ignore dont update else add the key with that value

Comment: Updated answer with append rather than replace for JSON arrays.

Comment: @colm.anseo thanks for the solutions have few questions: Q1. you used "if ok1 && ok2" any particular reason as we can also use "==" right? Q2. new to golang, but the function doesn't return the newConfig nor pointers are used to update fields how does the newConfig have updated values in main when printed? Q3. copyMap() is not even required right? i can just pass config in overlay()

Comment: @user17090811 Q1: `ok1` and `ok2` are booleans - so they both need to be true for the logic to work (`ok1==ok2` would not work as both may be false). Q2: Go `map`s are reference types, so no need to pass a map-pointer - as the function can update the maps in place. Q3: yes - if you want to iterate on the config via updates and don't care about keeping the old state - then yes there's no need to copy the map.